# глубокое клонирование массива

Tags: javascript

Дан массив arr['1','2',['3',{number:'4'}],'5'] нужно сделать его клон без использования методов slice и т.д. 
Написал пока только для массива

```
 var myArr =['1','2',['3',{number:'4'}],'5'];
var arrClone=[];
for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){
if(typeof(myArr[i])==='object')
{
    var arr=[];
    for(var j=0;j<myArr[i].length;j++){
        arr[j]=myArr[i][j];
    }


    arrClone[i]=arr;
}else { arrClone[i]=myArr[i]}

}
```

Comment: JSON.parse тоже нельзя юзать

Answer (score 1):

```js
function copyObject(obj){
  var copy = (obj instanceof Array)? [] : {};
    for (var key in obj) {
      if(typeof(obj[key]) === 'object'){
        copy[key] = copyObject(obj[key]);
      } else {
        copy[key] = obj[key];
      }
        
    }
    return copy;
}

var myArr =['1','2',['3',{number:'4'}],'5'],
    newArr = copyObject(myArr);


myArr[0] = 3;
myArr[2][1].number = 9999;

console.log(myArr, newArr);
```

В результате такого копирования получились две полностью независимые переменные, в каждой из которых хранится массив.

UPD: Обновил код.

Comment: А если вместо `myArr[0] = 3;` написать `myArr[2][1].number = 9999;`?

Comment: Хм, а собственно, почему вариант с простым присваиванием не подошёл?

Comment: @entithat там копируется ссылка на объект.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, тем не менее, если удалить первоначальную переменную, то будет работать, т.е. будут доступны элементы массива. Можете привести пример, когда это не сработает?

Comment: @Yaant, согласен, не прав, опять ссылка только копируется на объект.

Comment: @entithat ну тут главное слово "ЕСЛИ" удалить.

Comment: @Yaant поправил